# If Html File Has No Ending "/tr" Tag OR "/td" Tag Then HTML Agility Pack Does Not Read That Information Perfectly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am using HTML Agility Pack to parse html content. I am using parsing to extract table information.
It works. But if there is no ending "/tr" tag or "/td" tag then it does not parse that information perfectly.(in which there is no ending tr tag or td tag.)

Like

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content=
    "HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="xl27" valign="bottom" colspan="9">
            Sir / Madam,<br>
            I/We have this day done by your order and on your account the
            following transactions:
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boTRL" align="middle" colspan="5">
            Stamp duty as required under the relevant stamp act to be paid on
            consolidated basis at the end of the month.
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="30">
          <td class="xl27boTBL" align="middle" width="7%">
            Order No
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boTBL" align="middle" width="4%">
            Order Time
          </td>

          <td class="xl27boTBL" align="middle" width="5%">
            Net Rate
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boTBL" align="middle" width="5%">
            Service Tax
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boTBL" align="middle" width="5%">
           Amount
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boTRBL" style="BORDER-BOTTOM: windowtext 1pt solid;"
          align="middle" width="8%">
          Net Amount Rs
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="20">
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap width="7%">
            25222105
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap width="4%">
            14:02:39
          </td>


          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="right" width="5%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="right" width="5%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boRL" nowrap align="right" width="8%">
            125288.00 
          </td>

        <tr height="20">
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap width="7%">
            122122141
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap width="4%">
            14:01:56
          </td>


          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="right" width="5%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="right" width="5%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boRL" nowrap align="right" width="8%">
            249612.64 
          </td>

        <tr height="20">
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap width="7%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap width="4%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap width="7%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap width="4%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="left" width="15%">
            [SERVICE TAX]
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="right" width="5%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="right" width="5%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="right" width="5%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="right" width="7%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="right" width="5%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="right" width="5%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="right" width="5%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boL" nowrap align="right" width="5%">
             
          </td>
          <td class="xl27boRL" nowrap align="right" width="8%">
            61.66
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

So for that what should I do ?

```
<TABLE  cellpadding=1 cellspacing=0 Width='100%'  style='border:1px solid #FFFFFF;''>
<TRAlign='middle' VAlign='bottom' Class='clsTRFontBold'>
<TD NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr>ORDER NO</TD><TD NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr>ORD TIME</TD>
<TD  NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr>TRADE NO</TD><TD  NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr>TRD TIME</TD>
<TD  NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr ALIGN=CENTER>SCRIPNAME</TD>
<TD  NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr>BUY/SELL</TD><TD  NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr>QUANTITY</TD>
<TD NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr align=right>RATE (RS)</TD>
<TD NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr align=right>TOTAL (RS)</TD>
<TD NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr align=right>TOT BROK (RS)</TD>
<TD NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr align=right>SER TAX (RS)</TD>
<TD NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr align=right>STT (RS)</TD>
<TD NoWrap class=clsTRFontHdr align=right>NET TOTAL (RS)</TD>
</TR>

<TR Class='clsTRFont'>
<TD NoWrap>2009030267182768</TD>
<TD NoWrap>10:28:11</TD><TD NoWrap>66950592</TD>
<TD NoWrap>10:28:25</TD>
<TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD>
<TD NoWrap>BUY</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>366 </TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.2000</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>28621.20</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>-28621.21</TD></TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030267182768</TD>
<TD NoWrap>10:28:11</TD><TD NoWrap>66950783</TD><TD NoWrap>10:28:27</TD>
<TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>BUY</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>100 </TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.2000</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>7820.00</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>-7820.01</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030267182768</TD><TD NoWrap>10:28:11</TD>
<TD NoWrap>66956828</TD><TD NoWrap>10:29:39</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD>
<TD NoWrap>BUY</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>534 </TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.2000</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>41758.80</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>-41758.81</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030267510894</TD><TD NoWrap>11:06:12</TD><TD NoWrap>67137258</TD>
<TD NoWrap>11:09:24</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>SELL</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>162 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.2500</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>12676.50</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>3.1320</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>12673.36</TD></TR><TD NoWrap>2009030267510894</TD>
<TD NoWrap>11:06:12</TD><TD NoWrap>67137465</TD><TD NoWrap>11:09:28</TD>
<TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>SELL</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>200 </TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.2500</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>15650.00</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>4.1010</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>15645.89</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030267510894</TD><TD NoWrap>11:06:12</TD>
<TD NoWrap>67137479</TD><TD NoWrap>11:09:28</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD>
<TD NoWrap>SELL</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>4 </TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.2500</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>313.00</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.0773</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>312.91</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030267510894</TD><TD NoWrap>11:06:12</TD><TD NoWrap>67137995</TD>
<TD NoWrap>11:09:32</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>SELL</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>16 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.2500</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>1252.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.3093</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>1251.68</TD></TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030267510894</TD>
<TD NoWrap>11:06:12</TD><TD NoWrap>67138097</TD><TD NoWrap>11:09:34</TD>
<TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>SELL</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>100 </TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.2500</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>7825.00</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD>
<TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>1.9333</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>7823.06</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030267510894</TD><TD NoWrap>11:06:12</TD><TD NoWrap>67138333</TD><TD NoWrap>11:09:39</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>SELL</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>200 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.2500</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>15650.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>3.8666</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>15646.12</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030267510894</TD><TD NoWrap>11:06:12</TD><TD NoWrap>67138344</TD><TD NoWrap>11:09:40</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>SELL</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>318 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.2500</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>24883.50</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>6.1479</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>24877.34</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030268222556</TD><TD NoWrap>13:03:50</TD><TD NoWrap>67511545</TD><TD NoWrap>13:03:51</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>BUY</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>733 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.0000</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>57174.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>-57174.01</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030268222556</TD><TD NoWrap>13:03:50</TD><TD NoWrap>67511621</TD><TD NoWrap>13:03:53</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>BUY</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>2 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.0000</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>156.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>-156.01</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030268222556</TD><TD NoWrap>13:03:50</TD><TD NoWrap>67511797</TD><TD NoWrap>13:03:58</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>BUY</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>1 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.0000</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>-78.01</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030268222556</TD><TD NoWrap>13:03:50</TD><TD NoWrap>67512082</TD><TD NoWrap>13:04:05</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>BUY</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>264 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>78.0000</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>20592.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>-20592.01</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030268378000</TD><TD NoWrap>13:31:04</TD><TD NoWrap>67609079</TD><TD NoWrap>13:33:39</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>BUY</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>405 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>77.6000</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>31428.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>-31428.01</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030268378000</TD><TD NoWrap>13:31:04</TD><TD NoWrap>67609374</TD><TD NoWrap>13:33:46</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>BUY</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>45 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>77.6000</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>3492.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>-3492.01</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030268779359</TD><TD NoWrap>14:32:04</TD><TD NoWrap>67870192</TD><TD NoWrap>14:32:41</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>BUY</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>900 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>77.3000</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>69570.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>-69570.01</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030269013760</TD><TD NoWrap>15:03:56</TD><TD NoWrap>68018179</TD><TD NoWrap>15:03:56</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>SELL</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>146 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>76.2500</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>11132.50</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>2.8226</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>11129.67</TD>
</TR>
<!--tr tag missing-->
<TD NoWrap>2009030269013760</TD><TD NoWrap>15:03:56</TD><TD NoWrap>68018180</TD><TD NoWrap>15:03:56</TD><TD NoWrap>SESA GOA LTD</TD><TD NoWrap>SELL</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>10 </TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>76.2500</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>762.50</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.01</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.00</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>0.1933</TD><TD NoWrap ALIGN='RIGHT'>762.30</TD>
</TR>
<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0><br>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not including those tags?

Comment: Let whoever coded the table know that they can't code for "shizzle" :) - I'm not too sure to be honest, thought I would just say "that's some badly written HTML"

Comment: Html file is not written by me for which I write parsing code .And I want to write this parsing code such that it can parse any table information written by anybody.I am asking this question because I got such file where there is no end tag.

Comment: Hmm, that is an interesting problem. There are valid reasons for not including ending tags in some cases (Google for example). If you're scraping a page, perhaps ask the owner of the page to correct this?

Comment: There is particularly anything you can do, while the HTML parser in HTML agility pack is very resilient of malformed real world HTML (aka "tag soup") it can only do so much.

Comment: @Neurofluxation — It isn't badly written HTML. The end tags for td and tr elements are explicitly optional by spec (because the end of the element can be perfectly implied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tested my other idea and it didn't work, I think you have only two options:

1. Modify HTML Agility Pack to handle your case, or
2. Fill in the missing `</tr>`s yourself.

Here's a regex that might fill in the missing `</tr>`s for you:

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, "<tr[^>]*>(?:(?!</?tr>|</tbody>|</table>).)*?(?=<tr[^>]*>|</tbody>|</table>)", "$&</tr>", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

(If someone can improve my regex, please feel free.)

Comment: @Jeremy Stein..Thanks for the answer..Above regex works for small table but does not work for another table like I have put the table in the question which I had changed.

Comment: @Jeremy Stein.Thanks for the answer.Above regex works for that but I found another table in which this regex does not work.So I found html tidy as a solution.Thank you very much again for helping..

Comment: @Jeremy Stein,I was using html tidy pack and it inserts the missing closing tag but it also does other formatting what I don't want.I want to insert the missing tag only in the html file where necessary.So I want to use regex for that because only regex will fulfill my need but regex does not insert the </tr>  for above table which I have put in the question.

Comment: @Jeremy Stein,Thank You Very Much for helping..Your regex is very good and works very good...

Comment: @Jeremy Stein,If the starting tag is missing then which regex should be there ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Jeremy Stein,I have update my question with that example in which opeing tr tag is missing

Comment: It's unreasonable to expect to be able to parse such invalid HTML.  I suggest you switch to a regex to pull the data you need.

Comment: @Jeremy Stein,It's good feeling to get you back after many days,because I have this problem and I can not get it solved.But I can not switch to regex because it is almost to complete that project with parser and in only one file there is a problem like that.And html file is displayed properly of example which with I had updated my question which has missing opening tag.So if it is possible I want to use here regex to insert missing opening tags.

Comment: @Jeremy Stein, Is it possible with regex ?

Comment: Sure.  Download the evaluation version of RegexBuddy, copy in your HTML, and tweak a regex until it works.

Comment: @Jeremy Stein, Will you please help to make the regex for inserting opening tags in html file ?

Comment: You may want to do something like this: `html = Regex.Replace(html, "(?<=</tr>[^<]*)<td", "<tr>$&", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but does it help to add this code?

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("tr", HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("td", HtmlElementFlag.Closed);
```

Comment: @Jeremy Stein..It adds end tags but not at the appropriate location If there is a table like `<tr><td>firstrow</td> <tr><td>secondrow</td>` then and we do like `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Add("tr",HtmlElementFlag.Closed);` then the table will `<tr></tr><td>firstrow</td> <tr></tr><td>secondrow</td>` instead of `<tr><td>firstrow</td></tr> <tr><td>secondrow</td></tr>`

Comment: Thanks for following up.  Sorry I wasted your time on that idea.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a patch to HTML agility Pack that should make it able to deal with all optional end tags (though I permit a block inside a `<p>` at the moment).

It doesn't have much in the way of testing yet, but you can always give it a shot.  It's attached to the following Html Agility Pack bugreport:
http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/29218

Answer (score 0):

You can try  HTML Tidy  [Tidy.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/.).
 This seems to fix your issues.